# AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'append_page'

Tags: python, python-3.x, borb

I've installed the `borb` library using `pip` and I'm getting an error in the below block

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page

# Create document
pdf = Document()

# Add page
page = Page()
pdf.append_page(page)
```

In the above code I'm getting the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f883c75f0cd9> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 # Add page
      8 page = Page()
----> 9 pdf.append_page(page)

AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'append_page'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory; the `document` does not have any function to append the page. This may be due to the fact that (1) the actual function does not have have that attribute, (2) or you are typing it incorrectly.

In your case, I think it is a typo:

instead of `append_page()`; it should be `add_page()`.

https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb

Plus, from the above link, it seems that your 2nd import is incorrect; it should be:

`from borb.pdf import Page`